# Flex-lexer: Write state defines to a different file

Tags: flex-lexer

I want to use the start states of flex inside functions (and external files). Therefore I need the state definitions to be inside an external header file.

Is there any way of letting the definitions be written to an external file?

The code below shows an example of using the states inside functions defined inside the l-file

**lexer.l**

```
%{
   void changeState(){
     YY_START = MY_STATE;
  }
%}

%x MY_STATE

%%

 [ rules ]

%%
```

Comment: You don't really. Just write a series of functions to change the state by name, e.g. `changeToMyState() { YY_STATE = MY_STATE; }` etc.

Comment: This is exactly my example from above. But this doesn't work, because the functions are getting created before the state defines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

**lexer.l**

```
%x MY_STATE

%%

 [ rules ]

%%
  void changeState(){
     BEGIN(MY_STATE);
  }
```

Don't forget, that the upper section is actually only for declarations. Definitions should go in the last section. That way, they are places after the `#define` section